# Java and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, java

Until today I always have problem running Java with Ubuntu ?!
Is there a logical answer, why Java doesn't work as good with Linux as with Windows. I don't have a Windows Computer since several years and so I have to run Java with Linux.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "not working"? It's perfectly working. BUT. It comes with OpenJDK. Which is the open-source implementation (boo closed-source is evil). However, you can install the closed source Sun JDK/JRE with ease. ... Okay I can't find my answer.

Here it is:

> sudo add-apt-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner”
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts

That's it.

Here are the links:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-install-sun-java-runtime-environment-jre-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html
http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2010/05/21/installing-sun-java-in-buntu-10-04-long-term-support/
http://www.clickonf5.org/linux/how-install-sun-java-ubuntu-1004-lts/7777