# Install Java on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am a windows user, and wonder how do I go about installing java on Ubuntu (VirtualBox)

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin
```

got

> couldnt find package

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

got

> sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate

I also tried the .bin file:

```
sudo chmod 755 <filename>.bin
./<filename>.bin
```

Seems like it has done its things without errors, but

```
java -version
```

gives

> the program 'java' can be found in the following package ...

Comment: Total duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java and Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/156853/java-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sun Java has been moved to the Partner repository in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx).

Add the repository by doing this:

```
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
```

Then you can do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps to install Java 8 on Ubuntu:

1. At first,  download the package file from the official website.

   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. The download package is different for 64 bit and 32-bit versions.
2. You will need some superuser privileges to install JDK. So  use the following command-

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. The `/opt` directory is actually reserved for all the software and add-on packages. This software is not part of the default installation. The command for creating directory for JDK installation is

   ```
   mkdir /opt/jdk
   ```
4. Then extract java into the `/opt/jdk` directory:

   ```
   tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk
   ```
5. Then use the following command. This command verifies the file extraction into the `/opt/jdk` directory.

   ```
   ls /opt/jdk
   ```
6. By default, you can find java executable in `/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java` directory. To set it as the default JVM use:

   ```
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
   ```
7. Then verify the java has been successfully configured. Run the following commands:

   ```
   update-alternatives --display java
   update-alternatives --display javac
   ```

   You can check installation by

   ```
   java -version
   ```
8. You can also update Java. Hence, download an updated version of Oracle’s website and extract to the `/opt/jdk` directory. After that, set it as the default JVM with a higher priority number:

   ```
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk.new.version/bin/java 110
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk.new.version/bin/javac 110
   ```

Comment: Why is this preferable to installing from the repository?