# Installing Java 6 on Ubuntu 10.04 fails on missing Java 6 JRE package

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sun-java6-jdk

I'm trying to install Java 6 on Ubuntu 10.04 and it's been harder than it should be. In another question about [installing Java on Ubuntu/Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/166938/install-java-on-ubuntu-linux) it said that I needed to do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
```

However, that failed and I kept getting:

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

The solution to this, was to run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

So, that seemed to work and the command above to "add-apt-repository" seems to complete with no errors.  And I have run the following to confirm it got added.

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But, now when I run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

I get:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate

Where do I go from here?

Comment: [Answering your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) is perfectly acceptable, just make sure you put the answer portion as an actual answer by clicking on the "Answer..." link below.

Comment: Gotcha...  I will do that next time.  :)  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

So, the problem here was that I needed to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

works! But, you then are prompted to accept the user agreement.  I'm using Windows and Putty and it wasn't at all clear how accept this (clicking OK does not work).  I had to hit tab until it was highlighted.

This finally seemed to work.